# add specific dates in a file using python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a csv file containing 2 columns: id, val
where id is the number of the day (total 365)
Is it possible to convert the number id to dates in format '%d-%m-%Y'?
In fact I want to add all the days of year 2015 e.g. 01-01-2015 etc.
How can i do this with pandas in python?

following is a part of the file and the desired output

```
"id"    "val"
1   49
2   48
3   46
4   45


"date"  "val"
01-01-2015  49
02-01-2015  48
03-01-2015  46
04-01-2015  45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `id` to datetime and format the output with `strftime`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['id'].astype(str)+"-2015", format='%j-%Y').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Result:

|  | id | val | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 49 | 01-01-2015 |
| 1 | 2 | 48 | 02-01-2015 |
| 2 | 3 | 46 | 03-01-2015 |
| 3 | 4 | 45 | 04-01-2015 |

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.tseries.offsets.Day`:

```
df['date'] = pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01') \
             + df['id'].sub(1).apply(pd.tseries.offsets.Day)
```

Alternative, proposed by @HenryEcker:

```
df['date'] = pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01') \
             - pd.Timedelta(days=1) \
             + df['id'].apply(pd.tseries.offsets.Day)
```

```
>>> df['id'].sub(1).apply(pd.tseries.offsets.Day)
0    <0 * Days>
1         <Day>
2    <2 * Days>
3    <3 * Days>
Name: id, dtype: object


>>> df
   id  val       date
0   1   49 2015-01-01
1   2   48 2015-01-02
2   3   46 2015-01-03
3   4   45 2015-01-04
```

Comment: Seems like `pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01') - pd.Timedelta(days=1)` would be faster than subtracting from the entire Series and give the same results.

Comment: @HenryEcker. Thanks for this. I added your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns['date', 'val']
for i, contents in enumerate(df['date']):
    info = str(contents)
    if contents < 10:
        info = str(0) + info
    df['date'][i] = "01-" + info + "-2015"
```

This iterates through your column and converts it to date formatting

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.Timestamp('2014-12-31') + df['id'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(days=x))
```

Output:

```
   id  val       Date
0   1   49 2015-01-01
1   2   48 2015-01-02
2   3   46 2015-01-03
3   4   45 2015-01-04
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `x-1` to get the reference date untouched?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) on `id` column to turn its values into date offsets for adding to the base date, as follows:

```
df['date'] = pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(df['id'] -1, unit='day')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   id  val       date
0   1   49 2015-01-01
1   2   48 2015-01-02
2   3   46 2015-01-03
3   4   45 2015-01-04
```

If you want the date in `dd-mm-YYYY` format, you can use together with [`.dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), as follows:

```
df['date2'] = (pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(df['id'] -1, unit='day')).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   id  val       date       date2
0   1   49 2015-01-01  01-01-2015
1   2   48 2015-01-02  02-01-2015
2   3   46 2015-01-03  03-01-2015
3   4   45 2015-01-04  04-01-2015
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the years as the day count doesn't speak about which year to choose but you can convert it into months and dates.

change your csv column called id into the date. Then >>>

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%j').dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

it will change it into date. Then you can manually add year.